# Is there a way to force YAPF to always split/fold comprehensions?

Tags: python, yapf

How to force YAPF to always split/fold comprehensions like with `SPLIT_COMPLEX_COMPREHENSION` when `column_limit` is exceeded?

I have been trying many sorts of configuration setups - all to no avail. I'd rather avoid spraying over the codebase with `yapf: disable` for most of non-trivial comprehensions...